# Can Hartree-Fock-Bogoliubov be used for dynamics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, quantum-chemistry, mean-field-theory

I am aware of Hartree-Fock as both a tool to find interacting ground states for fermionic systems (eg the Roothan self-consistent field procedure). One way of deriving the ground state method is to start with the Hartree-Fock approximation (assuming a Fock state, which allows the factorization $\langle \hat{c}_\alpha^\dagger \hat{c}_\beta^\dagger\hat{c}_\delta\hat{c}_\gamma \rangle=\langle\hat{c}^\dagger_\alpha\hat{c}_\gamma\rangle\langle\hat{c}_\beta^\dagger\hat{c}_\delta\rangle-\langle\hat{c}^\dagger_\alpha\hat{c}_\delta\rangle\langle\hat{c}_\beta^\dagger\hat{c}_\gamma\rangle$, derive an expression for the energy in terms of the single-particle wavefunctions that make up the Slater determinant, optimize it with Lagrange multipliers, and then you've got the Hartree-Fock equations.

One could also use the Hartree-Fock approximation and this factorization to derive equations of motion for the single-particle wavefunctions, giving a a dynamical Hartree-Fock theory.

I have heard that there is an extension to Hartree-Fock known as Hartree-Fock-Bogoliubov, which includes some correlation effects via pairing. All the literature I can find on it appears to be focused on calculating ground states.

Is there such a thing as a dynamical Hartree-Fock-Bogoliubov approach? Can you use it to calculate dynamics? If so, where would I find more information on such an approach?

Comment: Yes, you can go beyond the HF mean-field approximation to include correlation effects. It goes by different names, such as random phase approximation, Bethe-Salpeter T-matrix equation, or
1/N expansion. See a ref here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370157394900221